# Filtering data in a datagridview using combobox

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview, combobox

Apologies - I am new to VS. 
I have created a DGV where pupils names and year groups appear - these are read from an array. 
Can anyone help with sample code as to how I would use a combobox to show the year groups separate. Eg. When you select year 9 - only year 9 pupils and their details will appear in the dgv. I do not have a database connected to the dgv.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Year 9")
     //something to change the dgv layout
    {
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered the same problem and the following code solved it for me:

```
(datagridview.DataSource as DataTable)DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("FIELD_NAME = '{0}'", "Year 9");
```

Replace FIELD_NAME with the name of your column you want to filter.

This filter, filters for the **exact** phrase "9 Years". If you it like this: '%{0}' it filters for all records which **end** with "Year 9".

The cast from the DataSource to a DataTable is necessary, because you want to filter the **data** and not the **datagridview**.